# MacBook Pro doesn’t recognize new internal HDD

Tags: mac, hard-drive

[image]

My MBP 13” mid 2012 doesn’t recognize new HDDs (500 GB HGST 5400 rpm SATA 3.0gb or 500GB HGST 7200 rpm 6.0g) in Disk Utility, but picked up a Toshiba 500 GB. My previous HDD failed(dead). I am confused; Is it really something with the brand, or rather a compatibility issue or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you try using this HDD with another computer (preferably a PC/non-Mac) and see if it works?

Comment: I’d also use a USB to SATA connector to validate the drive works before putting it inside the Mac or swapping an internal cable. Looks like there’s a decent answer so we can all edit that if needed

Comment: thanks.. yes i tried it other pc and it was brand new ,even i tried 3 different drives .. none worked. but as i mentioned toshiba 500 gb 5400 rpm got accepted but i want 7200 one in my computer

Answer (score 1):

The MBP 13" mid 2012 has some weirdness with the internal hard drive cable, which seems to be overly sensitive to many factors, including hard drive brand. I have seen trouble before with HGST drives and that model MBP.

Assuming you successfully tested the drive another way and found it working, I would try a new internal hard drive cable. Check the cable model number on its undeside, it's either 821-1480 or 821-2049. The former seem to be less reliable than the latter, so if you need to order a new one to test, I would order the latter.

Comment: Good advice. Also, you can use System Information when booted to recovery to make sure the system even sees the drive. You should see what speed the SATA bus negotiates and device details - that way you know the cable is connected or not in some cases before doing the actual repair.

Comment: i am confused.. if there is something wrong with cable then why it picked toshiba drive? sorry i am not a expert of such things

Comment: It was confsing me too at first. I am simply speaking from my own experience, I have replaced dozens of these cables in that exact model for my clients due to many different "weird" symptoms, from slowness and error prone reading and writing, to half-boots to non responsive drives.
I am not aware of any solid documentation on this, official or otherwise, but the fact is that Apple changed the cable from one model to another while producing this model MBP, so they must have figured out something was sub-optimal too.